# Why the submitted data is not getting displayed in the URL when an HTML form is submitted using "get" method?

Tags: php, forms, post, get, form-submit

I'm using **PHP 7.0.2**

Consider following HTML form code :

```
<form action="foo.php" method="get">
    Name:  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
```

Consider file **foo.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

After filling the form fields I submitted the form by clicking on the Submit button. Then the REQUEST array values get printed but I didn't see those values in the URL of a browser like a query string.

How did that happen? I expected to see the form fields values in my browsers's URL as I am submitting the form using **"get"** method.

If this going to happen then what's the difference between using **"get"** method and **"post"** method for submitting an HTML form to some PHP file?

Comment: your code is working fine. restart (wamp or zamp)

Comment: Browser?  Server?  Server setup?

Comment: @Progrock : I'm using XAMPP on my Windows 10 machine. The web browser is HTTP Apache server.

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` after submission?

Comment: @Progrock : It's showing string(3) "GET"

Comment: Again, asking what is your web browser?  Opera obscures query parameters in the address bar.

Comment: @Progrock : Opera 49.0

Comment: Click in the address bar to show the query parameters in Opera.